# Help me identifying this round sans serif font

Tags: fonts, font-identification

[image]

I've used it a long time ago and now I can't find it. I've used all font recognizers and those don't seem to work.

Comment: Are you saying that it was you who had created the logo you show? Or how else are you sure that this is an actual font and not custom artwork for "Sound of Moves"?

If you want other users to sleuth with and for you, the more info you can provide, the better. Like what system where you on "a long time ago"? Did you use commercial fonts or just free stuff?

Also search Graphic Design for many other font identification requests, you will see several useful tools and websites mentioned in the answers or comments.

Comment: I tried at identifont.com but got 131 results and my internet is too slow to look at them all. If you find more examples set in this font, i.e. more characters, we might still find it. Or if your internet is faster than mine, browse through all options on identifont.

Answer (score 1):

[Fonarto Font Family](https://www.1001fonts.com/fonarto-font.html) via 1001fonts.com

[image: Fonarto1]
[image: Fonarto2]

Comment: awesome. did you just know it when you saw it, or do you know some special online tool please?